# Regex Match Only On Specific Word AND 1 Occurence

Tags: regex, redirect, iis

Really sorry if this has been posted but I can't quite find a solution, despite looking (almost) everywhere! Any assistance will be greatly appreciated :)

Basically, I'm setting a redirect up in IIS using regex. I need a pattern so that it matches only if 2 conditions are true:

a word (phrase I guess) "**/sub-page**" is found

**AND**

there is only **1** occurence

This is a correct test:

http://website.com/en/sub-page/

Incorrect Test:

http://website.com/en/sub-page/sub-page

I've tried this but it isn't quite working:

(?:^|\W)(/sub-page)(?:$|\W)

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?<!/sub-page\b)/sub-page\b(?!/sub-page\b)`

- `(?<!/sub-page\b)` = negative lookbehind, to make sure the sub-page doesn't appear before the current position in the URL
- `/sub-page\b` = find the literal `/sub-page` followed by a word boundary
- `(?!/sub-page\b)` = negative lookahead to make sure that the sub-page doesn't appear after the current position in the URL

together it means `/sub-page\b` must match only once, anywhere in the URL.

example: https://regex101.com/r/fS2eF7/1

Comment: note that IIS uses a Perl 5 compatible regex flavor (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/danielvl/2008/06/06/url-rewrite-for-iis-7-0-regular-expressions-and-wildcards/) but regex101 doesn't have this option, so I chose Python there to show the example, which has similar enough behavior for this regex.

Comment: The solution looks good. The only concern is that look behind is not supported in JavaScript. For reference try doing that here http://regexr.com/

Comment: @maverick28 OP says he is using an IIS redirect, so limitations of JavaScript shouldn't be relevant. See the blog post I linked to in my comment that shows that IIS redirect rules support Perl 5 compatible regex.

Comment: @KeithHall Thank you very much Keith! That has worked perfectly. I really appreciate you helping me, especially done in such a clean and precise way.